# Suddenly get a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: internal-server-error

My website was working fine for weeks until two days ago, then on every page besides the homepage I'm getting:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

The error log says:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

How do I fix this?

Also, what could've caused it so I know how to prevent it in the future?

Comment: Whoever wrote the website would know about any redirects that are supposed to happen. You need to tell us what application wrote to the error log.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm a n00b about this stuff (probably why I needed some to build a website for me). Does apache port 80 mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting? (I know, its obvious)

Comment: Do you mean rebooting my computer? (can't believe I just asked that)

Comment: I don't know how. But strangely my website has just started working again. I changed the htaccess file then reverted it back and it works again. I'm still unsure of what happened in the first place though.

Comment: I dont know about htaccess files, but if you change them, does it restart the application? That may have happened to get it going again?